# Tape drive unusable on 14.04 ESXi VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, ubuntu-14.04, tape, scsi, tapedrive

### The problem

I've got an Overland ArcVault connected to my system (actually a virtual machine, with the standalone SCSI card it's connected to in passthrough mode), but it seems like the named tape device nodes (something like `/dev/st0` or `/dev/nst0`) i'd expect to see are not being created, and the few nodes that are created don't fully work right.

In particular, I see five devices being created, `/dev/sg0` through `sg4`.

`sg0, 1`, and `2` represent the virtual disk drives connected to the VM.

`sg4` is the device that represents the tape library itself, **and it works correctly** - that is, I can use commands like `mtx` to control it.

From the boot messages, `sg3` is the actual drive itself, but it resists all attempts at access.  Attempts to do things like `mt -f /dev/sg3 rewind` always return an `Operation not permitted` error. I've verified that the library has mounted a tape in the drive, and have tried this with all of the `sg*` devices.

There also exists a `/dev/tape/by-id/scsi-200900d09126c0024`, but this is just a symlink to the library at `sg4`.

### The question

How do I actually access the tapes, and why can't my system pick it up?

### The Background

---

#### lsscsi

```
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00  /dev/sr0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sda
[2:0:1:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sdb
[3:0:1:0]    tape    HP       Ultrium 4-SCSI   W51H  -
[3:0:1:1]    mediumx OVERLAND NEO Series       0510  -
```

(note: no special device node created)

#### relevent dmesg

```
[    3.666897] scsi host3: ioc0: LSI53C1020A A1, FwRev=01032700h, Ports=1, MaxQ=255, IRQ=16
[    4.558084] scsi 3:0:1:0: Sequential-Access HP       Ultrium 4-SCSI   W51H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    4.558334] scsi target3:0:1: Beginning Domain Validation
[    4.565558] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.565635] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.565711] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.565787] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.565863] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.565938] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.566013] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.566088] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.566164] scsi 3:0:1:0: mptspi: ioc0: IDP:ON
[    4.624137] scsi target3:0:1: Ending Domain Validation
[    4.624361] scsi target3:0:1: FAST-160 WIDE SCSI 320.0 MB/s DT IU RTI PCOMP (6.25 ns, offset 64)
[    4.628877] scsi 3:0:1:1: Medium Changer    OVERLAND NEO Series       0510 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.888235] scsi 3:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 1
[    7.888784] scsi 3:0:1:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 8
```

(so the tape drive lives at 3:0:1:0, which looks like it would be `sg3`)

#### tapeinfo, sg4

```
Product Type: Medium Changer
Vendor ID: 'OVERLAND'
Product ID: 'NEO Series      '
Revision: '0510'
Attached Changer API: No
SerialNumber: '2B31000036'
SCSI ID: 1
SCSI LUN: 1
Ready: yes
```

#### tapeinfo, sg3

```
Product Type: Tape Drive
Vendor ID: 'HP      '
Product ID: 'Ultrium 4-SCSI  '
Revision: 'W51H'
Attached Changer API: No
SerialNumber: 'MXP113433K'
MinBlock: 1
MaxBlock: 16777215
SCSI ID: 1
SCSI LUN: 0
Ready: yes
BufferedMode: yes
Medium Type: Not Loaded
Density Code: 0x46
BlockSize: 0
DataCompEnabled: yes
DataCompCapable: yes
DataDeCompEnabled: yes
CompType: 0x1
DeCompType: 0x1
BOP: yes
Block Position: 0
Partition 0 Remaining Kbytes: 800226
Partition 0 Size in Kbytes: 800226
ActivePartition: 0
EarlyWarningSize: 0
NumPartitions: 0
MaxPartitions: 0
```

(medium type: not loaded?!)

#### edit 1

Some more digging, it appears the `st` kernel module responsible for controlling tape drives is not loaded, nor can I load it.

modprobe st output

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='st'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'st': Function not implemented
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:959 command_do() Error running install command for st
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'st': Operation not permitted
```

Is there an apt package containing this module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -generic kernel that comes with Ubuntu does not contain the `st` module responsible for controlling tape drives. That module can be found in the 'extra' kernel package.

```
apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
modprobe st
```

And one `dmesg` later-

```
[57218.963458] st: Version 20101219, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
[57218.966611] st 3:0:1:0: Attached scsi tape st0
[57218.966614] st 3:0:1:0: st0: try direct i/o: yes (alignment 512 B)
[57218.991321] st 3:0:1:0: [st0] Block limits 1 - 16777215 bytes.
```

And all is right with the world :)

Aside: This is the kind of thing that would really do well to be included in Ubuntu's documentation. I'd expect a server install image to come with things like tape drive modules already...

Comment: Ubuntu is kinda crappy in terms of following standards. This would not be an issue in the Red Hat ecosystem.